# How to disable Ctrl+Click on OS X?

Tags: macos

I've noticed that Ctrl+LeftClick emulates RightClick (the same way Apple+LeftClick emulates the MiddleClick). Is there any way to disable the default action for Ctrl+LeftClick on OS X? (currently using 10.5).

*Update:* I am using a four-button Logitech "UltraX Optical Mouse," nothing fancy: http://goo.gl/AKZw

Comment: So you don't want it to emulate RightClick? And what kind of mouse are you using?

Comment: Actually, given the history of the single-button mice on the Mac, I guess that right-click emulates Ctrl-click ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having difficulties doing Ctrl+Click in VNC clients when I'm connected to Windows XP machines.

When using OS X's built-in Screen Sharing as your Mac's VNC client, then Ctrl-click is sent to Windows servers just fine. (You'll actually *need* a multi-button mouse then to do a Windows-like right-click. That is: the only way I know how to do a right-click in a Windows-session with Screen Sharing is actually right-clicking.)

To start Screen Sharing, hit Cmd-K in Finder and type some URL that starts with `vnc://` To create a shortcut in 10.6, first connect to the remote server and then drag the proxy-icon (the little icon in the menu bar, left of window title) somewhere. In 10.5, one can create a shortcut by dragging the `vnc://` URL from the Safari location bar (address bar) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `shift + ctrl + right click` to get the the normal `ctrl + right click` functionality in VNC to Windows or VMWare etc.

Tested in OSX 10.7.4 with Windows in VMWare 4.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the OS. Ctrl+Click is the command for a context menu.

Some (not all) mouse drivers support right-clicking to emulate ctrl-click. Not the other way around. If you don't use it, then don't use it. Nobody is forcing you to, and no Mac application will use ctrl-click for anything else. (Command-click, yes, like Illustrator.)

Comment: Actually, I'm having difficulties doing Ctrl+Click in VNC clients when I'm connected to Windows XP machines. Yes, I am being forced to use it.

Comment: Why taking rep points off when the question is unclear

Comment: not the downvoter, but I suppose somebody didn't like your tone of "If you don't use it, then don't use it".  there are many valid reasons to want to use control-click for something other than right click.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem using the Microsoft Remote Desktop Client.

What actually works: Clicking first and then pressing Ctrl instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cmd + click
```

This will fall back to

```
ctrl + click
```

In most of the applications.

Confirmed to work in Google music for me.

Comment: in javascript, a command click shows up as an alt click